# Download large files through PHP from Azure Storage account

Tags: php, azure, nginx, web-applications, azure-storage-account

I'm building a website on an Azure WebApp to download large files (4GB and up). The actual files are stored in a file share in an Azure storage account. This file share is mounted into the WebApp, so PHP can access the files.
PHP can read the folders and file info without issues, but the downloading fails. I can download the files fine and they are identical in size compared to the files on the webserver, but the files are corrupt as they are filled with PHP errors:
`<b>Notice</b>:  ob_flush(): Failed to flush buffer. No buffer to flush in <b>/home/site/wwwroot/SoftwareDownload/download.php</b> on line <b>37</b><br/>`
This is what the download.php looks like:

```
<?PHP
    set_time_limit (86400); //24 hours
    
    IF (isset($_GET['FileName']))
    {
        $FileName=$_GET['FileName'];
        header ("Content-Type: application/zip");
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header ("Content-Length: " . filesize($FileName));
        $DownloadFileName = basename($FileName);
        header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$DownloadFileName\"");
        readfile_chunked($FileName);
    }
    ELSE
    {
        echo "No File Specified!";
        die();
    }

    
    // Read a file and display its content chunk by chunk
    function readfile_chunked($filename, $retbytes = TRUE) 
    {
        $ChunckSize=50*1024; // 50K buffer
        $buffer = '';
        $cnt =0;
        $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
        if ($handle === false) 
        {
            return false;
        }
        $BytesProcessed=0;
        while (!feof($handle)) 
        {
            $buffer = fread($handle, $ChunckSize);
            echo $buffer;
            ob_flush();
            flush();
            if ($retbytes) 
            {
                $cnt += strlen($buffer);
            }
        }
        $status = fclose($handle);
        if ($retbytes && $status) 
        {
            return $cnt; // return num. bytes delivered like readfile() does.
        }
        return $status;
    } 
?>
```

I have tried replacing the whole thing with a simple

```
fpassthrough($FileName);
```

but then the download won't even start. I have tried with different buffer sizes in the start of the readfile_chunked function, but that did not help either. Obviously I do not want PHP to read the file completely into memory (as that would require way to much memory and take too long) before offering it for download.
Can anyone help me getting the files downloaded without errors?

Comment: `the files are corrupt as they are filled with PHP errors`...you should configure your PHP to log errors and warnings to a file instead of to the standard output, as the first step.

Comment: [`fpassthru()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru) takes a file handle, not a filename.

Comment: With fpassthru and a filehandle the download runs smoothly and without errors. Thanks for pointing out my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using fpassthru function using a filehandle instead of a filename:

```
$FileHandle=fopen($FileName,"rb");
fpassthru($FileHandle);
```